wpa enterprise, shared user, security
I recently started working at a company with a WPA 2 enterprise network, where multiple Devices (let's say all) share the same Radius user account. Basically the employees use the enterprise network as if it were a WPA personal network, where shared account+password is replacing the shared passwort.
Are WPA 2 enterprise networks secure against this kind of abuse? Obviously https and other encryption mechanisms aside from the Wifi would mitigate the problem, but that is besides the question.
My hope would be that WPA 2 Enterprise Networks work with per client encryption, such that individual clients would not be able to (simply) sniff each others (otherwise unencrypted) traffic, even if they use the same radius account.
cheers
Edit, clarification: My primary concern with this question was whether there are any security measures in wpa 2 enterprise at all (such as unique shared keys per client) that would mitigate the above abuse.


Are WPA 2 enterprise networks secure against this kind of abuse?

No, not without prohibiting exchange and sharing of such information.

My hope would be that WPA 2 Enterprise Networks work with per client encryption

Yes, that's the general idea. If you permit your users to share accounts & passwords you can just use PSK.
If admins are too lazy to generate individual accounts for devices then there may be something wrong with the process.

Marked as solved, thank you. If you could point me to official documentation regarding this (per client encryption in wpa2 enterprise with shared account), I would be especially grateful.

I'm afraid that's not part of the WPA-ENT, IEEE 802.1X or EAP/RFC 3748 standards. It's pretty much common sense as mentioned above (if you permit...) and should be part of your certificate deployment policy, usually part of the corporate security policy.

Are WPA 2 enterprise networks secure against this kind of abuse?
No. Why would a cheap, inadequate technology help with a problem as old as time? It doesn't.
In a normal network, you know that a person performed an access, because only they have their password. You don't have that now, and you must assume a malicious actor can and will get the credentials.

Thank you. I clarified my question in the original post (see: edit). I would like to know whether there is any security at all against abuse like i described - since this is obviously not the usecase wpa 2 enterprise was designed for.
